# How to format string in boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I want to format string with boost library in C++. I am doing as below.

```
std::string msg = "Version: %1. Version %2.";
boost::format formatter(msg.c_str());
formatter % "v1" % "v2";
xyz_function(msg);
```

We can do that with sprintf in one statement so is there a way to optimize above boost implementation for string formation in one statement or something other ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [At the top of the very first page of the Boost format documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) is a one-line example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **`boost::format`** object can be cast to a string and it also has an explicit conversion function.

```
boost::format fmt
    = boost::format("Luke %1% and Han %2%.") % "Skywalker" % "Solo";
```

So either of these can be used:

- `std::string fmtStr = boost::str(fmt);`
- `std::string fmtStr = fmt.str();`

See [example and demonstration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/format/example/sample_new_features.cpp), and [*Boost Library Format; getting std::string*](/q/4168437) for the `boost::str` tip.

Comment: One Question: Should it be "%1" or "%1%" ?

Comment: The documentation uses the surrounding percent symbol format, so `%1%` is the right format.